# Images don't displayed on screen

Tags: flutter, filepicker.io

I have modified my code. I thought I could achieve what I am willing to do but I am still having an issue. The first image is fine, but when I am adding more images, they don't display to the screen. The idea is to allow the user to click on a button to select one or several images. Then, he can tap on a second button and add one pfd file, it is like adding attachment in email.Then, if the user wants he can tap on the first button and add an other image. The list of all the documents should be displayed on the screen. I though that maybe a set State is missing somewhere. Here is the code. I do not understand where is my mistake. Thank you in advance.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

List<PlatformFile>? _paths;
List<String> filesGB =[];
bool _loadingPath = false;
String fileExtension='';
String _fileName='';

// To access the pictures
  void _openPictureFileExplorer() async {
    setState(() => _loadingPath = true);

    try {
      _paths = (await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
        type: FileType.media,
        allowMultiple: true,
      ))?.files;

      if (_paths != null) {
        _paths!.forEach((element) {
        filesGB.add(element.path.toString());
        print(filesGB);
        print(filesGB.length);
        });
        setState(() {
        });
      }
      } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("Unsupported operation" + e.toString());
    } catch (ex) {
      print('$ex');
    }

    if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      _loadingPath = false;
    });
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('File Picker app'),
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),

                      //#############
                      //Display card with button to select type of document
                      child: Card(
                          child:
                          Container(
                            // color: Colors.red,
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                //Attachement
                                FlatButton(
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                  child:
                                  InkWell(
                                    child: Container(
                                      //  color: Colors.white,
                                        child: Column(
                                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment
                                              .center,
                                          children: [
                                            Icon(Icons.attach_file),
                                            Text('Attachment'),
                                          ],
                                        )
                                    ),
                                    onTap: () async {
                                      fileExtension = 'pdf';
                                      _openDocumentFileExplorer();
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),

                                //Photo
                                FlatButton(
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                  child:
                                  InkWell(
                                    child: Container(
                                      //   color: Colors.white,
                                        child: Column(
                                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment
                                              .center,
                                          children: [
                                            Icon(Icons.add_a_photo_rounded),
                                            Text('Photo'),
                                          ],
                                        )
                                    ),
                                    onTap: () {
                                      fileExtension = 'jpeg';
                                      _openPictureFileExplorer();
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )),
                    ),
                    Builder(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => _loadingPath ?
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                        child:const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      )

                      : filesGB.isNotEmpty ?
                      Column(
                            children: listOfCards(filesGB),
                      )
                     :Text('Nothing to display'),
                ),
    ]),)))));
  }
}

List<Widget> listOfCards(List<String> item){

  List<Widget> list = <Widget>[];
        ListView.builder(
           itemCount: filesGB.length,
           itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
         return new Container(
            height: 114,
            child: GestureDetector(
              child: Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                  ),
                  elevation: 10,
                  child: ClipPath(
                    clipper: ShapeBorderClipper(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15))),

                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          height: 113, width: 113,
                          child: Image.file(File(item[i].toString()),
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            width: double.infinity,),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            child: Text(item[i]
                                .split('/')
                                .last),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),),
            ),
       );
  });
  return list;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you don't need to use `for loop` for building your pictures list
just use `ListView.builder`

but about your problem, I think it happens because you set selected pictures in a row
then return that row as a child of your column

so your pictures align horizontally and column just show widgets in vertical aligns

in other words, your column just have one child, and its a Row
so column just show pictures as possible then you just see the first picture.

---

for solving this problem you should return a list of widgets in the `listOfCards` function

just do these simple changes and I hope your problem solved

change your function return parameter to `List<Widget>`

```
Widget listOfCards(List<String> item) {
```

to

```
List<Widget> listOfCards(List<String> item) {
```

then just return your list

```
return list;
```

and your column should look like this

```
Column(
   children: listOfCards(filesGB),
)
```

Comment: Thank you. The reason I was using For loop it is to get the index and to be able to remove a card hen the user click on delete. I will modify my code as you suggest and will come back to you in few minutes

Comment: I have updated the code. I will copy it in my first question

Comment: I have tried but no image is displayed. I do not know why.

Comment: if you want to use `ListView.builder`  you should return the `ListView.builder` not the variable `list`
and the function return parameter must be `Widget` instead of `List<Widget>`
and use `Container` instead of `Column`

Comment: Please, can you confirm if this is what you mean?
```
 
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            child: Text( 'Text' ),//item.split('/').last),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),),
            ),
       );
  });
  return ListView.builder(itemBuilder: itemBuilder);

}
```

Comment: I am getting this error: A value of type 'ListView' can't be returned from the function 'listOfCards' because it has a return type of 'List<Widget>'. when I write return ListView.builder

Comment: `List<Widget> listOfCards(List<String> item) {`

 to

 `Widget listOfCards(List<String> item) {`

Answer (score 0):

I have find a working solution. It does what I was expecting with image. I still have a problem when I delete a record, the card is not removed. I do not find where I should use the setState. I will continue to investigate.

```
body: Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),

                      //#############
                      //Display card with button to select type of document
                      child: Card(
                          child:
                          Container(
                            // color: Colors.red,
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                //Attachement
                                FlatButton(
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                  child:
                                  InkWell(
                                    child: Container(
                                      //  color: Colors.white,
                                        child: Column(
                                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment
                                              .center,
                                          children: [
                                            Icon(Icons.attach_file),
                                            Text('Attachment'),
                                          ],
                                        )
                                    ),
                                    onTap: () async {
                                      fileExtension = 'pdf';
                                      _openDocumentFileExplorer();
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),

                                //Photo
                                FlatButton(
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                  child:
                                  InkWell(
                                    child: Container(
                                      //   color: Colors.white,
                                        child: Column(
                                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment
                                              .center,
                                          children: [
                                            Icon(Icons.add_a_photo_rounded),
                                            Text('Photo'),
                                          ],
                                        )
                                    ),
                                    onTap: () {
                                      fileExtension = 'jpeg';
                                      _openPictureFileExplorer();
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )),
                    ),
                    Builder(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => _loadingPath ?
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                        child:const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      )

                      : filesGB.isNotEmpty ?
                      Column(
                        children: getList(),//[listOfCards(filesGB)],
                      )
                     :Text('Nothing to display'),
                ),
    ]),)))));
  }
}

List<Widget> getList() {
  List<Widget> childs = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < filesGB.length; i++) {
    childs.add(
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: (){
            print ("Pressed");
          },
          child: Card(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
            ),
            elevation: 10,
            child: ClipPath(
              clipper: ShapeBorderClipper(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15))),
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 113,width: 113,
                    child: fileExtension == 'pdf'?
                    Image.asset('assets/logo_pdf.png',
                      // fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      //  width: double.infinity,
                    ):

                    Image.file(File(filesGB[i].toString()),
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      width: double.infinity,),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Text(filesGB[i].toString().split('/').last,//_nameOfFile,//name,
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right:25.0),
                    child: IconButton(onPressed: (){
                      //delete a record and the card displaying this record
                     // Delete the selected image
// This function is called when a trash icon is pressed
                      if (filesGB.length > 1) {
                        filesGB.removeAt(i);
                        print(filesGB);
                        setState(() {});
                      }
                    },

                      icon:Icon (Icons.delete, color: Colors.red,),),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            //subtitle: Text(path),
          ),
        ));}
  return childs;
}
```